# IntelliJ IDEA highlights @Entity class names with "Cannot resolve symbol" in JPQL

Tags: jpa, intellij-idea, annotations, jpql

IntelliJ IDEA highlights persistent @Entity class names with "Cannot resolve symbol" in red in JPQL which is distracting and buries real issues.

So, for example, I declare a query in my repository:

```
private static final String READ_BY_CANDIDATE_KEY = "SELECT cr FROM Entity AS cr left join cr.relationship AS re left join fetch cr.relationship2 WHERE re.candidateKey=:ID";
```

.. and "Entity" is underlined, even though "Entity" is a valid class name, and has the @Entity annotation. When the code actually runs, there are no problems.

I imagine some sort of configuration is required to let the IDE know what classes are valid? How is that configuration done?

**Update**: I do have a JPA facet, but it doesn't see the annotated classes. It seems to require a persistence.xml or orm.xml (which my project does not use)

Answer (score 62):

Seems like you have not selected the default JPA provider in facet configuration. Depending upon which provider you are using, pick one from the list. Available options are EclipseLink, Hibernate, OpenJPA, TopLink

Comment: Where do I set this exactly?

Comment: Go to File > Project Structure > Facets. Then click on the + icon and add JPA to your project/module. After you've done this, you can select a Default JPA Provider.

Comment: I have only Android, Android Artifact, Android-Gradle, APK, Java-Gradle, Kotlin, Native-Android-Gradle as options.

Answer (score 25):

Make sure you have [JPA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-jpa-support.html) or [Hibernate](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-hibernate-support.html) facet [configured](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/hibernate-and-jpa-facet-pages.html) in IntelliJ IDEA for your module.

Comment: Are you using Spring? If so, Spring facet is required.

Comment: could you provide instructions on how to do the above please?

Comment: If you are using Spring for your JPA config (no persistence.xml) just create a JPA facet and set the default JPA Provider.  No xml file needs to be specified.

Comment: You also have to right-click the root item in the Persistence menu and hit Assign Data Sources... then pick your DB and you should be all set

Comment: @Amalgovinus For Spring Boot applications there is nothing to choose from. Even when you create JPA and/or Hibernate facets manually, list stays empty.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Spring Boot with maven, add this dependency in your `pom.xml` file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

File -> Project Structure

At left pane select "Facets". If there is no JPA listed, click "+" sign and add "JPA"

At bottom of same dialog, at "Default JPA Provider", select - "Hibernate", press "OK"

If you have error at @Table annotation, configure and choose data source

Table name for select now should be recognized  as entity class name

Answer (score 2):

you would have missed this dependency- Spring data JPA
This one is for Maven projects

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

add this one in your POM under dependencies section
and then use **ctrl+click** on **@Entity** to import it from

> import javax.persistence.Entity;

for **Gradle** follow the same and use

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
```

under dependencies in the build.gradle file

Comment: For gradle, make sure you refresh gradle, so that it rebuilds in Intellij for this to come in effect.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same symptom as the OP (IntelliJ highlights entity in JPQL with the error "Cannot resolve symbol") but the solution turned out to be invalidating the IntelliJ caches and restarting the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this dependency if you are using Spring-boot.
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes JPA Buddy plugin brakes the springboot JPA configuration. Make sure this is not causing the issue.

Comment: I'm the head of JPA Buddy development team. So, I wonder what case you have mentioned? As we have never faced something like this and don't even touch the configuration part... Could you please provide more information, so we could fix the problem if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency in pom.xml correctly, for me this fixed it:

1. Right click your project -> Maven -> Reload project

[image]

This fixed also for me error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'Query'"