# How to remove data source warnings in Spring Jpa and Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

After new update Intellij, I have red warnings in entity classes. For example:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "poll_answers", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "poll_id"))
    private Set<String> answers;
```

I have warning lines under "poll_answers" and "poll_id" "cannot resolve table/column" and offers me press "assign data source".

Comment: Please mention the __version of IntelliJ__ (after and before update)! Which plugin (or source) does send this warning?

Comment: Have you set up the database in IntelliJ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intellij IDEA: specify datasource for JPA validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356148/intellij-idea-specify-datasource-for-jpa-validation)

Comment: @hc_dev maybe, but I use annotations

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I use application.properties to connect to database

Comment: IntelliJ has a database tools window, there you can set up the connection and IntelliJ can then check the table and columns

Comment: @P.J.Meisch but if I used to use just app.properties + database ? without intellij tools

Comment: the IntelliJ shows you the warning. You can configure the corresponding inspection to not mark this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your setup: Spring, JPA, ORM

Since your Spring project uses JPA and you are defining object-relational-mappings (ORM) using annotations:

```java
@JoinTable(name = "poll_answers", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "poll_id"))
```

IntelliJ is intelligent and tries to **validate** the specified *tables* and *columns* **against the database**.

You can get an idea of the magic from this [tutorial](https://jpdevelopment.blogspot.com/2015/11/create-entity-objects-from-db-schema.html), although the topic is slightly going into another direction.

You did not really provide the settings/setup (JPA Facet, etc.) that you are using within your IntelliJ project. It would be ideal if you can provide more information or a screenshot.

#### Warning issue

Since you apparently have **no database/data-source assigned** within your *IntelliJ Database Tools* window, the above explained validation fails and the reported warning is shown:

> cannot resolve table/column

#### Possible solution and further help

A solution may be, to **add the Data Source** as the warning popup suggests already.

Maybe this [tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/intellij-idea/example/21702/database-tools) can help you to setup a new Data Source within *IntelliJ Database Tools*.
You can use your **JDBC connetion-string** (starting with `jdbc://`) from your mentioned `application.properties` to configure your database-connection.

In my comment to your question I also pointed you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14358573/5730279) here, which pictorally describes how to **Assign Data Sources** via the IntelliJ menu: **View** -> **Tool Windows** -> **Persistence**.

Comment: Do so, if you want to learn how to take advantage of these warnings! As [P.J. Meisch commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59127293/spring-jpa-intellij-entity-class-red-warns-under-fields-types-sources/59146149#comment104549677_59127293) you can also ignore or disable warnings and your application will compile and run anyway.

Comment: it compiles fine even with them. But i dont like to see that red warning. If that was yellow... .

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ignore such warnings without having to configure a data-source inside IntelliJ you can do that by removing the particular inspection in Settings under :
`Editor > Inspections`.

The proper selector should be under:
`JPA > Unresolved database references in annotations`

[image]

[Source: IDEs Support (IntelliJ Platform)](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206363599-Annoying-underline-in-my-sql-statement)