# Intellij doesn't recognize h2 table

Tags: intellij-idea, h2

I´tm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/08/restful-api-spring-rest-data-jpa-h2.html), but theres an error in the @Table annotation:

> Cannot resolve table 'EMPLOYEE'

What i need to do so intellij recognizes the h2 database and eliminate this error?
[image]

Comment: This table must exist in database you have configured for project and must be visible in [Database tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/database-tool-window.html). Also the persistence unit must be associated with this data source. Check [Intellij IDEA: specify datasource for JPA validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356148/intellij-idea-specify-datasource-for-jpa-validation) and [Associating persistence units and session factories with data sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-persistence-tool-window.html#assign_data_source)

Answer (score 0):

This table must exist in database you have configured for project and must be visible in [Database tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/database-tool-window.html). Also the persistence unit must be associated with this data source. Check [Intellij IDEA: specify datasource for JPA validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356148/intellij-idea-specify-datasource-for-jpa-validation) and [Associating persistence units and session factories with data sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-persistence-tool-window.html#assign_data_source)

Comment: As far as i understand, the data source will created as soon the app is running , accordingly to the tutorial.But this is not happening

Comment: `the data source will created as soon the app is running` you need to set up data source manually, please see [Connect to a database](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html).