# IntelliJ IDEA can't resolve entity in spring data jpa @query annotation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, intellij-idea

Here is my `repository` interface:

```
public interface ContentRepository extends JpaRepository<Content, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select c from Content c where c.ContentCategory.genre =  :genre and c.ContentType.genre = :contentType")
    Iterable<Content> findByTypeAndCategory(@Param("contentType") String contentType, @Param("genre") String genre);

}
```

And Here is `Content` POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
public class Content implements Serializable {

public Content() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@ManyToOne
private ContentCategory contentCategory;

@ManyToOne
private ContentType contentType;

// other methods }
```

And here my `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.aa.bb"/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.aa.bb.repository"/>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="2323"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.tarameshgroup.derakht.repository"/>

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

compiler can't find `Content` in `@Query`

Comment: Does it work in Eclipse ???

Comment: @SkorpEN I don'y have Eclips, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Does simplest JPA example work in your IntelliJ ???

Comment: @SkorpEN No, it can't find `Content` entity at all.

Comment: Did It work on entity generated by IntelliJ ???

Comment: Does comparing generated entities to your entities solved problem??

Comment: Copy compiler error message.

Comment: To question. preferably in code tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA highlights @Entity class names with "Cannot resolve symbol" in JP QL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420996/intellij-idea-highlights-entity-class-names-with-cannot-resolve-symbol-in-jp)

Comment: I have the same problem with Spring Boot and IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1: 
- no persistence.xml - entities are highlighted with red underline. 
- add any persistence.xml - entities are highlighted correctly.

Comment: are you sure its `c.ContentCategory.genre` and not `c.contentCategory.genre` with a lowercase c in content??

Comment: Does the code compile and does the query run properly?  Not sure if you are having issues above and beyond IntelliJ's inspection of the Query.

Comment: Have you selected the default JPA provider in your facet configuration?

Comment: Go to File > Project Structure > Facets. Then click on the + icon and add JPA to your project/module. After you've done this, you can select a Default JPA Provider.

Answer (score 2):

Three problems:

1. You don't have the JPA facet activated (this is what underlines the Content type in @Query in red)
2. Your packages are incorrectly set, packageToScan should be set to your entities package
3. You should reference properties in @Query, not types (I see weird `content.ContentCategory.genre` in uppercase)

After that, you should see Content type resolved in @Query AND be able to run your query correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface ContentRepository extends JpaRepository<Content, Long> {

@Query(value = "select c from Content c where c.ContentCategory.genre =  :genre and c.ContentType.genre = :contentType")
Iterable<Content> findByTypeAndCategory(@Param("contentType") String contentType, @Param("genre") String genre);
```

I am pretty sure that there is a capitalization issue:

```
@Query(value = "select c from Content c where c.contentCategory.genre =  :genre and c.contentType.genre = :contentType")
```

You had the types (e.g., c.**C**ontentCategory), not the field names (e.g., c.**c**ontentCategory).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't quoted the package of your Entity. Please make sure it is in the classpath scan you have set in the applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 0):

A few things can cause this.  First thing to try is to make sure you have a JPA Facet correctly setup:

- Go to Project Structure, select Modules and check your module in the
  list has a JPA facet.  If it doesn't then add one.
- If that alone doesn't help, then also try looking at your Spring config.  You've show that the package(s) to scan for entities is *com.tarameshgroup.derakht.repository*

  `<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="...">
       ...
       <property name="packagesToScan"
                 value="com.tarameshgroup.derakht.repository"/>`

  However is that the *exact* package that the entity resides in (your code doesn't show).  I've had IDEA problems where I have sub-packages and although the app runs correctly if I define the top-level package as you have, IDEA doesn't automatically pick them up for syntax highlighting purposes.  So, for example, if I have package `com.foo.bar.domain` with some entities in, as well as `com.foo.bar.domain.subpkg` and my Spring config had a `packagesToScan` value of just `com.foo.bar.domain` then the entities in that package would have correct highlighting, but not the sub-package.  The answer was to change the Spring configured `packagesToScan` value to include the sub-packages, even though Spring itself doesn't require this, i.e. `com.foo.bar.domain, com.foo.bar.domain.subpkg`

Answer (score 0):

```
c.contentCategory.genre
```

instead

```
c.ContentCategory.genre
```

and

```
c.contentType.genre
```

instead

```
c.ContentType.genre
```

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't always resolve entity in spring data jpa @query annotation, it resolve it in runtime since you can create/modify entities when your application starts, e.g. using Hibernate ***create*** and/or ***create-drop***.
There's a IntelliJ setting that you need to set correctly in order not to get this error - see IDEA IntelliJ's documentation.

You may need to add "Configure JPA or Hibernate facet" quick fix in IntelliJ.

**Another** possible solution can be using ***NamedQuery*** in the entity **POJO**. Example code:

```
@NamedQueries(
 {          
 // AclEntries
 @NamedQuery(
      name = GET_CONTENT_BY_GENRE_AND_CONTENT_TYPE,
      query = "select c from Content c where c.ContentCategory.genre =  :genre and c.ContentType.genre = :contentType"
 )
 }
)
@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
public class Content implements Serializable {
public static final String GET_CONTENT_BY_GENRE_AND_CONTENT_TYPE = "Content.selecCfromContentWhereGenreAndContentType";
public Content() {
}
...
}
```

You use it like this:

```
List contentResults = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Content.GET_CONTENT_BY_GENRE_AND_CONTENT_TYPE)
.setParameter("genre", "parameter-genre-value")
.setParameter("contentType","parameter-contentType-value")
.getResultList();
```

Comment: another posible solution can be using ___NamedQuery___ in the entity __POJO__. Example code:

Answer (score -1):

Two solutions come to mind:

1. Create a JPA facet with the persistence.xml
2. Connect to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1 in your database tab (usually in the right sidebar)

The second solution has fixed most of the problems I had with Intellij query highlighting.