# How to delete/getList using JPA in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have an ***entity***:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="cats")
public class Cat {
    @Id
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="age")
    private int age;

    @Column(name="color")
    private String color;

    @Column(name="weight")
    private int weigth;
  ..
}
```

**1**. I need to ***delete*** it from database using ***EntityManager***:

```
@Override
public void delete(Cat cat) {
    entityManager.remove(cat);
}
```

**Problem**: I have a `Map<String, Cat>` which contains all this elements. I get it by name from map *IllegalArgumentException* -> "Removing a detached instance com.entities.Cat#cats".

***Question***: How can i do it ***without getting*** from database by key?

**2**. I need to getList with ***limit*** and ***offset***.

To ***get all*** the elements i can just use:
 `entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT name, age, color, weight FROM cats");`

Without ***entityManager*** i used ***prepatedStatement*** with:

```
"SELECT name, age, color, weight FROM cats LIMIT ?,?"
```

***Question***:
How can i do it using ***entityManager***?
Do ***entityManager*** have something like ***preparedStatement***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `EntityManager` you can use `Query` objects. It provides you with several different methods to build your queries, which you can see in the [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html).

From there, you can use a `Query` to perform a select or execute an update into the db.

Update example:

```
//:id is a parameter you can set
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("delete from Entity e where e.id = :id");
query = query.setParameter("id", id);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Select example (using `TypedQuery` which implements `Query`:

```
String sql = "select e from Entity e";
TypedQuery<Entity> query = entityManager.createQuery(sql, Entity.class);
System.out.println(query.getResultList());
```

You can determine limit and offset like this:

```
query = query.setFirstResult(offset);
query = query.setMaxResults(limit);
```

If you have an entity at hand you **can** (and should) delete it using your `EntityManager` with `remove()`. You're getting that error because your entity is detached - that is, your `EntityManager` isn't aware of its existence.

To "attach" entities to your manager you can use `merge()`. However, if said entity doesn't exist in the database it will be inserted, and if it exists but has different fields from your object it will be updated.

```
public void delete(Cat cat) {
    if(!entityManager.contains(cat)) {
        entityManager.merge(cat);
    }

    entityManager.remove(cat);
}
```

To insert entities for the first time you can also use `persist()`. For the differences between `merge()` and `persist()`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509086/what-is-the-difference-between-persist-and-merge-in-jpa-and-hibernate).

Comment: I am having only a little problem with it - when i am trying to get list it works, but in String sql = "select e from Entity e" compiler says "Can't resolve symbol Entity"

Comment: That's because you should replace "Entity" with your own class

Comment: I replaced, it was just for an example where i have a problem

Comment: Please add stack trace

Comment: It works but intellij idea says "can't resolve symbol Cat" in my case. But when i am trying to run it, it gives me correct result, without exceptions, errors etc.

Comment: If the query is working then it's working. Have you added all required imports?

Comment: Yes, it propose me to read more about it - "This inspection controls whether the Persistence QL Queries are error-checked".

Comment: Check this out, might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420996/intellij-idea-highlights-entity-class-names-with-cannot-resolve-symbol-in-jpq

Comment: Project Structure - Facets - add - JPA. Just added it in my project(even without specifying config jpa xml) and now i don't have this error message.

Comment: Is it possible to specify firstResult as: i have @ID of entity, i need some quatity of elements after an element with this @ID?

Comment: The question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959811/how-to-getlist-using-jpa-when-the-first-entity-is-the-following-entity-after-the

Comment: If you're ordering by ID and want from the first onwards you can just use an `ORDER BY` clause

Answer (score 1):

1. If you need to use `EntityManager`, then simply use reference:

   ```
   entityManager.remove(entityManager.getReference(Cat.class, id));
   ```

   This way the entity won't be fetched from db, but will be deleted.

   Using query is also an option:

   ```
   Query query = entityManager.createQuery("delete from Entity e where e = :entity");
   query = query.setParameter("entity", entity);
   query.executeUpdate();
   ```
2. You can create `Query` using `EntityManager#createQuery`. Then set parameters:  `firstResult` and `maxResults`:

   ```
   query.setFirstResult(10).setMaxResults(20);
   ```

   This will take 20 entities starting from 10th.