# Intellij IDE show error highlight in Entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, entity

I open a spring boot project in *IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)*, and I hot many error highlight in entities, like:

- Cannot resolve table 'roles'
- Class 'RolesEntity' should have [public, protected] no-arg constructor
- Cannot resolve table 'user_roles'

But when I open my project in old version like *IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3 (Community Edition)* I don't see this problem.

**IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2**

[image: IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2]

**IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3**

[image: IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3]

**Any reason for this problem or any fix please?**

Comment: Hello Doesn't Matter, Can you check my answer?

Comment: @AvijitBarua Hi, I don't check it yet, but when I will, I return to you +1 any way ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IntelliJ idea go to

**Setting-> Inspections->JPA->Unresolved database reference in annotations-> severity(which is just right)-> change  from error to week warnning.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

---

File -> Project Structure

At left pane select "Facets". If there is no JPA listed, click "+" sign and add "JPA"

At bottom of same dialog, at "Default JPA Provider", select - "Hibernate", press "OK"

If you have error at @Table annotation, configure and choose data source

Table name for select now should be recognized as entity class name

---

Reference : [GintsGints - stackOverFlow userName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420996/intellij-idea-highlights-entity-class-names-with-cannot-resolve-symbol-in-jpq)

Answer (score 0):

Try to click File> Invalidate Cache & Restart. This should help