# IntelliJ cannot resolve symbol 'NULL' in JPA @Query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

In any `@Query` in a Spring Repository, IntelliJ inspection is highlighting `NULL` with a red underline, saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'NULL'". Note that changing the case to all lowercase doesn't to fix it. [After checking similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420996/intellij-idea-highlights-entity-class-names-with-cannot-resolve-symbol-in-jpq) I did ensure I have the JPA & Spring facets configured properly.

Note this isn't actually an issue at runtime or compile time; everything actually works fine. It's just annoying/distracting seeing the highlights in IntelliJ. Does anyone know how to resolve this, or why it is happening?

Below is a minimal example showing the issue.

[image: example]

I am using

- IntelliJ Ultimate `2021.3.2`
- spring-data-jpa `2.3.4.RELEASE`
- openjdk 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to basically be a non-issue in newer versions of Intellij.

Answer (score -3):

Set the `nativeQuery` attribute to true, something like:

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true,value="")
```

Comment: You cannot use nativeQuery there. The select is using JPA objects not database table names.

Comment: NULL keyword cannot be used when using JPA objects

Comment: Why can't NULL be used with JPA objects? The query works fine, IntellIiJ's inspection just highlights it (seemingly incorrectly)